# Custom search function for jQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete).

Is there a way to override its default search algorithm?

The changes I want to make are:

- Prioritize words that *start with* the search term at the top of the suggested results.
- Return a maximum of 5 results (instead of the default behavior, which is to return all matching results, potentially creating a really tall dropdown box).

Answer (score 2):

Normally, it all should be done in back-end. Your server-side script defines in what order and how many results will be returned.

Alternatively (if back-end is not under your control), you can specify function as `source` attribute. In this function you can query back-end and process results in whatever way your want. E.g., here's an example
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple-remote

Comment: The data is on the front end already, so I don't need to do anything with the back end. I just need to change the way the results are ordered.

Comment: @Emmett Ok, I misunderstood it. According to the docs, your only option now is using function as source and doing comparisons/ordering manually. You can also use another (possibly more popular) autocomplete plugin which has option to limit number of results and many more: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete